# SyntaxError "��c" at Module.compile when running node.js server using `index.js` as entry

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to get the express.js hello world application to run, but I'm running into an issue when I try to run `node index.js` from powershell.

The tutorial I am following is here: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

And my code is the same as the tutorial, but I have posted it below.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

When I run `node index.js` I get a weird syntax error posted below.

```
��c
^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

However when I change the entry point in package.json to app.js and change the filename from index.js to app.js, everything works correctly. Why is this?

Comment: How is the file encoded?

Comment: It's probably the case that you cut-and-pasted the code into your editor from the website. Just delete and manually re-type the first line of your code. That will get rid of the invisible characters (probably "zero-width space").

Answer (score 0):

You have bad characters in your file.

If you are in Visual Studio Code, navigate to View -> Render Control Characters. This should show the bad characters in your file.